# How to output multidimensional array to json with php?

Tags: php

I have a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [İSTANBUL FATİH SULTAN MEHMET EĞİTİM ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ] => Array
        (
            [HAZİRAN 2014] => 1.132173
            [TEMMUZ 2014] => 1.072592
            [AĞUSTOS 2014] => 1.149672
            [EYLÜL 2014] => 1.072698
            [EKİM  2014] => 2.398888
            [KASIM 2014] => 1.957187
        )


)
```

I want to out put this array like this json format:

```
{
name:'İSTANBUL FATİH SULTAN MEHMET EĞİTİM ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ',
data:[1.132173,1.072592,1.149672,1.072698,2.398888,1.957187]
}
```

How can we do this with php?

Comment: [RTFM](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose something like this will do the trick:

```
function to_json_data($input)
{
    $name = key($input);
    return json_encode(['name' => $key, 'data' => array_values($input[$name])]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**json_encode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). However, to obtain what you expect you need to change a bit the array in PHP.